# Hack the [hacking] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What does [hacking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking) mean? Is it anything like [black-hat](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-hat)? Or does it mean “I'm doing something clever”? Or “look how l33t i am”?

There's no tag wiki, and the list of questions is a hodgepodge of “I meant [defense](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense)”, “I meant [attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attacks)”, “I meant [forensics](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forensics)”, “I meant security”, “I had no idea how to tag this”, …

Does the tag have any use, or should it be burninated?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed - I have had a read through the 32 questions tagged [hacking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking) and it does not add any value. I have replaced that tag on all the questions where it was the only tag, and will request burnination.

And done!

Comment: This has been added to the blacklist.